# Pass login id to another page through session variable with PDO page

Tags: php, session, pdo, session-variables

I am unable to pass login id through SESSION Variable after login with pdo.

This is loginc.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../../configPan/config.php');
extract($_POST);



        $q = $pdo->prepare("select * from `distributor` where psa_id= ? and password= ? ");
        $q->execute(array($un,$pw));



        if($q->fetch())
        {
        $_SESSION['psa_id'] = $un;
        header("location:home_page.php");


        }
        else
        {
        $_SESSION['e']="Sorry...! Your username or password is incorrect.";
        header('location:../index.php');
        }


?>
```

This is config.php

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'pan_online';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
?>
```

In the home.php page I want to get psa id with the following code. but fails to retrieve data. it always shows "no data"

```
<?php $user = $_SESSION['psa_id'];
        $_q=$pdo->prepare("select * from distributor where psa_id=?");
                $_q->execute([$user]);
                if($_q->fetch()){
                echo "Center: " . $_q['psa_id']; }else{echo "no data";} ?>
```

Comment: echo $_SESSION['psa_id']; & check if data is coming or not

Comment: @Ashu 'root" comes when using <?php echo $_SESSION['psa_id']; ?> not psa id

Comment: 'root' is  your user name? if yes then check loginc.php.here you are storing $un in $_session['psa_id']..

Comment: @Ashu I am logging with id "asd"  not 'root'

Comment: Do you do `session_start()` on home.php…?